# smartgwt position of mouse event

Tags: mouseevent, smartgwt

I'm trying to position a context menu in a Smart GWT Canvas, by using 
`
            addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

```
            public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
                                    getContextMenu.setRect(rect)
                getContextMenu().show();

            }
        });
```

`

The problem is that theres doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to get the X/Y coordinates of my mouse click event, which I can use to create the rect. I can get the AbsoluteTop & absoluteLeft of the enclosing Canvas, but that doesn't help me position the context menu window accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecordClickEvents are usually used with ListGrids. With a Canvas you can use [ClickEvent](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/events/ClickEvent.html), which has getX() and getY() methods.

```
addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
    }
});
```